# IntPtr allow implicit conversion from ulong to long

Tags: c#, intptr

```
class A
{
    public static explicit operator A(long mm)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
UInt64 ul = UInt64.MaxValue;
IntPtr ptr = (IntPtr)ul;//no error
A a = (A)ul;//Cannot convert type 'ulong' to 'A'
```

why do IntPtr allow the behavior?

following is IL code:

```
.entrypoint
.maxstack 1
.locals init (
    [0] uint64 ul,
    [1] native int ptr)
L_0000: nop 
L_0001: ldc.i4.m1 
L_0002: conv.i8 
L_0003: stloc.0 
L_0004: ldloc.0 
L_0005: call native int [mscorlib]System.IntPtr::op_Explicit(int64)
L_000a: stloc.1 
L_000b: ret
```

Comment: It might be interesting to inspect the IL generated by the above using ildasm to see if it treats IntPtr as a native int and hence performs the conversion using [conv.i](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.conv_i%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: @ Dan, I don't think so. any reference to "C# Language Specification"?

Comment: @Vince, I imagine this would be part of the ECMA-335(CLI spec) not ECMA-334(C# spec). IntPtr is considered a 'native int' data type. Which I am guessing being able to explicit cast between every built-in valuetype is in the spec. Something worth testing might be to see if this works in VB.Net and other .net languages. Along with testing to see if this works in monodevelop. That way you can more easily narrow down if this is C# specific or MS specific. I'm guessing this is part of the CLI spec somewhere though.

Comment: thanks for your answer. we need more knowledge for correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that this seemed a bit odd, so I ran a couple of tests.

#### Test #1: Do a cast of a ulong and a long

```
ulong ul = UInt64.MaxValue;
long l = Int64.MaxValue;
IntPtr ulptr = (IntPtr)ul;
IntPtr lptr = (IntPtr)l;
```

Because the `IntPtr` cast states that it may throw an `OverflowException`, I was expecting the  `(IntPtr)ul` cast to throw an exception. It did not. Imagine my surprise when the `(IntPtr)l` cast threw an `OverflowException`. Looking into this, I saw that my project was set to compile for `x86`, so the exception now made sense -- `Int64.MaxValue` is too large to fit into a 32-bit `IntPtr`.

#### Test #2: put a `checked` block around the same code.

Now, I really expected the `(IntPtr)ul` cast to throw an exception, and it did.

This made me wonder what was going on with the first cast. Using `ildasm` on the unchecked code leads to the following:

```
IL_0000:  nop
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.m1
IL_0002:  conv.i8
IL_0003:  stloc.0
IL_0004:  ldc.i8     0x7fffffffffffffff
IL_000d:  stloc.1
IL_000e:  ldloc.0
IL_000f:  call       native int [mscorlib]System.IntPtr::op_Explicit(int64)
IL_0014:  stloc.2
IL_0015:  ldloc.1
IL_0016:  call       native int [mscorlib]System.IntPtr::op_Explicit(int64)
```

So -1 is put on the stack and converted to an `int64`, but there's no extra conversion from an unsigned to a signed `int64`.

The `checked` version is slightly different:

```
IL_0000:  nop
IL_0001:  nop
IL_0002:  ldc.i4.m1
IL_0003:  conv.i8
IL_0004:  stloc.0
IL_0005:  ldc.i8     0x7fffffffffffffff
IL_000e:  stloc.1
IL_000f:  ldloc.0
IL_0010:  conv.ovf.i8.un
IL_0011:  call       native int [mscorlib]System.IntPtr::op_Explicit(int64)
IL_0016:  stloc.2
IL_0017:  ldloc.1
IL_0018:  call       native int [mscorlib]System.IntPtr::op_Explicit(int64)
```

Now there is a cast from unsigned to signed, which is necessary in case of overflow.

Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the original question.

**Update:** I removed the portion of the answer that was incorrect, thus leaving no actual answer. However, I expect it is helpful so I have not deleted the entire answer.

Comment: I have a quick look your reference from Eric Lippert. But here it seems not suitable, becuase no standard conversion from ulong to long.
and take a look at my sample class A. I defined a explicit operator as IntPtr, but A donesn't behave as IntPtr. Thanks for your reference. I'll take more time to study.

Comment: @Vince, there is an explicit standard conversion from ulong to long, and per Eric's answer, the explicit cast to IntPtr allows for the explicit conversion to be done.

Comment: no. range for ulong is different from that for long. ulong.Max>long.Max ulong.Min>long.Min.

Comment: @Vince, range being different is exactly the reason why the conversion is explicit and not implicit.

Comment: @Jole, from ulong to long(or from long to ulong) is explicit conversion but is not standard explicit conversion. refer "CSharp Language Specification". 6.3.2 says "if a standard implicit conversion exists from a type A to a type B, then a standard explicit conversion exists from type A to type B and from type B to type A." 6.3.1 lists which implicit conversions belong to standard implicit conversion, and 6.1.2 lists implicit numeric conversions belonging to standard implicit conversion.

Comment: @Vince, Yes, I'm seeing my mistake here. I suspect I'm very near the answer, but haven't actually found the answer.

Comment: @Jole, still thanks for your answer. I'd like spend more time one studying C# specification.:)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27469/discussion-between-vince-and-joel-rondeau)

Answer (score 2):

The `IntPtr` and `UIntPtr` types are just managed representations of an address which itself is a number.  Hence it provides conversions between values which are logically numeric and of the same signed / unsignedness.

In this case `UIntPtr` is unsigned and hence only provides conversions to unsigned numeric values like `ulong`.  This is incompatible with the explicit operator on `A` which accepts a `long` (signed) value.

You need to either add an extra operator for `ulong` or do an explicit cast to `long` from `UIntPtr`

```
A a = (A)(long)ul;
```

Comment: here is IntPtr instead of UIntPtr.:) I think it should only allow conversion from long to IntPtr. It's strange.